# ionic 2 sample conference app can't find babelify module

Tags: npm, ionic2

I am learning ionic2. I thought the sample app was a good starting point but unfortunately, I can't get it work. It complained about missing module.Please see the output:

```
lola@ubuntu:~/pj/ionic-conference-app$ ionic serve

Running 'serve:before' gulp task before serve 
[08:53:57] Starting 'sass'...
[08:53:57] Starting 'html'...
[08:53:57] Starting 'fonts'...
[08:53:57] Starting 'scripts'...
[08:53:57] Finished 'scripts' after 63 ms
[08:53:57] Finished 'html' after 115 ms
[08:53:57] Finished 'fonts' after 114 ms
[08:53:58] Finished 'sass' after 888 ms
[08:53:58] Starting 'watch'...
✗ Caught exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'babelify' from '/home/lola/pj/ionic-conference-app'
at /home/lola/pj/ionic-conference-app/node_modules/ionic-gulp-browserify-es2015/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
at process (/home/lola/pj/ionic-conference-app/node_modules/ionic-gulp-browserify-es2015/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
at ondir (/home/lola/pj/ionic-conference-app/node_modules/ionic-gulp-browserify-es2015/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
at load (/home/lola/pj/ionic-conference-app/node_modules/ionic-gulp-browserify-es2015/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
at onex (/home/lola/pj/ionic-conference-app/node_modules/ionic-gulp-browserify-es2015/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
at /home/lola/pj/ionic-conference-app/node_modules/ionic-gulp-browserify-es2015/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15) 

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues

$ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.22
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.12
OS:
Node Version: v4.4.2
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: did you run `npm install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely, you need to update NPM which will include the babelify dependencies. Check your version of NPM by running `npm -v` , it should be v3.x. Run sudo `npm install -g npm` to update npm. and you should be good to go.

Comment: I believe there is no need to install project packages globally, locally would be enough

Answer (score 0):

Just `npm install` in project root worked for me.